# Very tight prime bounds

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it possible that

$$\left|\operatorname{li}(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor}\dfrac{\pi(n^{1/k})}{k}-\log(2)-\dfrac{1}{2}\right|<\dfrac{2\sqrt{n}}{e\log(n)}?$$

[image]

Since

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor}\dfrac{\pi(n^{1/k})}{k}\approx\operatorname{li}(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2\ \Re\left(\operatorname{Ei}\left(\rho_k\log\left(n\right)\right)\right)-\log(2)
$$
(where $\rho_k$ is $k$th zeta zero) shown as a partial sum below

[image]

and since $\pm\dfrac{2\sqrt{n}}{\Im(\rho_1)\log(n)}$ bounds $2\ \Re\left(\operatorname{Ei}\left(\rho_1\log\left(n\right)\right)\right)$
[image]

does it follow that $\pm\dfrac{2\sqrt{n}}{C\log(n)}$ will bound $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2\ \Re\left(\operatorname{Ei}\left(\rho_k\log\left(n\right)\right)\right)$ for some $C$ (assuming RH)?

*$C=e$ seems particularly tight.*

This is of course, almost identical to saying

$$|R(n)-\pi(n)|<\dfrac{2\sqrt{n}}{e\log(n)}$$ where $R$ is the Riemann prime counting function, but this is a little too tight since this doesn't hold for $n=113$.

## Note

The log plot is particularly striking:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I will start by making it clear that this is not my answer.

Since this question generated a fair amount of interest and had not been answered, I thought it best to cross-post on MO & then link back for the benefit of those who starred it.

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176869/tight-prime-bounds?answertab=votes#tab-top) is the link to [GH from MO](https://mathoverflow.net/users/11919/gh-from-mo)'s answer.

Comment: Maybe should mark it CW then...+1 for your question!