# Prime bounds under RH

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis

Continuing from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865820/very-tight-prime-bounds), since

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor}\dfrac{\pi(n^{1/k})}{k}=\operatorname{li}(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2\ \Re\left(\operatorname{Ei}\left(\rho_k\log\left(n\right)\right)\right)-\log(2)+\int_{n}^{\infty}\dfrac{\operatorname{d}t}{t(t^2-1)\log(t)}
$$

and since

$$\left|2\ \Re\left(\operatorname{Ei}\left(\rho_1\log\left(n\right)\right)\right)\right|\leq\dfrac{2\sqrt{n}}{\Im(\rho_1)\log(n)},$$

surely, it follows that

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2\ \Re\left(\operatorname{Ei}\left(\rho_k\log\left(n\right)\right)\right)\right|\leq\dfrac{2\sqrt{n}}{C\log(n)}$$

for some $C$ *(assuming RH)*. If this is the case, then

$$\operatorname{li}(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor}\dfrac{\pi(n^{1/k})}{k}-\log(2)+\int_{n}^{\infty}\dfrac{\operatorname{d}t}{t(t^2-1)\log(t)}=O\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\log(n)}\right)$$

Would it not then follow that
$$\pi(n)=\operatorname{li}(n)+O\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\log(n)}\right)?$$

Are these not the "best possible" prime bounds under the RH, rather than

$$\pi(n)=\operatorname{li}(n)+O\left(\sqrt{n}\log(n)\right)?$$

Comment: You seem to assume that $\Im(\rho_k)\le C$ for all $k$, but this is false.